# Predictability of $\int^t_0 f(X_s)\,\mathrm ds$ where $X$ is a Lévy process

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X_t$ be a Lévy process and $f(x)$ some smooth function. Under what conditions is 
$$
Y_t = \int^t_0 f(X_s)\,\mathrm ds$$
predictable?

Not sure how to investigate this. It is clearly adapted, so I have tried to look at it in terms of continuity. It seems like it should be continuous but not sure how to proceed with that either.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Since any left-continuous (adapted) process is predictable, we have in particular that any continuous (adapted) process is predictable.

Comment: @saz Thank you, but not sure if I understood the implication of that. Are you saying that $Y_t$ is continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\omega \in \Omega$. Since the mapping $s \mapsto X_s(\omega)$ is càdlàg, we have

$$\sup_{s \in [0,t]} |X_s(\omega)| < \infty$$

for any $t \geq 0$. As $f$ is continuous, this implies in particular that

$$M:=\sup_{s \in [0,t]} |f(X_s(\omega))|<\infty.$$

Hence, $$\left| Y_t(\omega) - Y_r(\omega) \right| = \left| \int_r^t f(X_s(\omega)) \, ds \right| \leq M |t-r|$$ for any $t,r \geq 0$. This shows that $s \mapsto Y_s(\omega)$ is even Lipschitz continuous (on compact sets). Since any continuous adapted process is predictable, the claim follows.